# How to create an aggregate query in JS where $in contains null?

Tags: parse-platform, mongodb-query, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

This MongoDB query executes fine in the shell:

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "language": { "$in": [null, "en"]}
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

The query returns documents where the `language` field is missing or has value `null` or `en`.

I try to create the same query with the Parse SDK in Javascript:

```
const query = new Parse.Query("MyCollection");
const pipeline = {
    "match":{"language":{"$in":[null,"en"]}},
};

const results = await query.aggregate(pipeline);
```

The query returns only documents where the `language` field has value `en`, but not where the field is missing.

How can I get the same results in JS?

Comment: Have you tried with `undefined` instead of `null`?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo `Undefined` is not a value recognized by MongoDB and it is not the same as `null`. In addition, `undefined` would be removed by the parse REST controller because it uses `JSON.stringify` to create the request body string.

Comment: I know that. In the database you can have either null or undefined (if you haven't set anything). But it really seems to be a bug. I actually also tried this `{"match":{"$or":[{"language":"en"},{"language":null},{"language":{"$exists":false}}]}}`. It matches the undefined value but not the null ones. Do you mind to open an issue in the repo? I will take a look.

Comment: Done https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/920